# How to have both Hilt and non-Hilt Android Instrumentation Tests in androidTest

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-espresso, dagger-hilt, androidjunitrunner

**TLDR; How to configure android instrumentation tests to run, so that we can have some hilt based tests and some which do not need hilt**

I am able to create and run a simple espresso test with Jetpack compose but then I wanted to add `hilttestrule` and mock those dependencies. I followed this google [hilt guide](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#early-entry-point) pretty accurately and was able to get hilt tests working but the initial `createAndroidComposeRule` won't work anymore with this error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The component was not created. Check
> that you have added the HiltAndroidRule.

The root cause is that I am modifying the `testInstrumentationRunner` to
`testInstrumentationRunner = "com.example.CustomTestRunner"` and my customTestrunner which looks like this

```
class CustomTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, name: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, HiltTestApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

is forcing a `HiltTestApplication` even for tests that do not need hilt configuration.

**Some wacky ideas that didn't work**

1. Can I have multiple testInstrumentationRunners? If so, how can I configure them to be picking up different tests. Can I send some flags into defaultConfig from tests
2. Or can I configure the CustomTestRunner to be only applicable when there is a specific Annotation on the tests? eg:

```
  override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, name: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        return when {
            runnerArgs.filters == androidx.filters.Large -> super.newApplication(cl, MyApp::class.java.name, context)
            else -> super.newApplication(cl, HiltTestApplication::class.java.name, context)
        }
    }
```

But runnerArgs is private and invisible to child classes and I can't access it.